# Use DryIoC in FreshMVVM

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, inversion-of-control, dryioc, freshmvvm

In the [README.md](https://github.com/rid00z/FreshMvvm/blob/master/README.md#custom-ioc-containers) of the FreshMVVM repo it is explained which interface has to be implemented to use any other IoC container besides the built-in version of TinyIoC.

Is there anyone here who already created a implementation for DryIoC and get it to work properly? I'd know how to implement the functions like `Register<RegisterType, RegisterImplementation>` and `Resolve<RegisterType>`, but besides that I'm more or less lost. Also it seems that if I use a custom IoC container implementation pages and their viewmodels cannot be resolved without explictely registering them in the first place. This is not necessary with the built-in container.

Comment: Did you ever get your issues solved? Particularly "if I use a custom IoC container implementation pages and their viewmodels cannot be resolved without explictely registering them in the first place."

Comment: Not really. I just went with creating my own dependency injection "framework" to register and resolve views, etc.